# RedHat for desktops

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, linux-distributions, wubi

Is there any RedHat variant for desktops and FREE? If yes, is there any Wubi like tool that can be used to install from within Windows XP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a free (as in money) version of Redhat linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/15602/is-there-a-free-as-in-money-version-of-redhat-linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 main forks are [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org) and [CentOS](http://centos.org). You can use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to configure an install over the internet or from an ISO. The configuration can be done in Windows, and once you reboot you will have a boot menu containing Windows and your Linux distribution. Choosing the Linux distribution will bring you through the regular installer. A great tutorial on the process can be found [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/unetbootin_windows_ubuntu_fedora_p2).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's called [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/) now. No WUBI is an Ubuntu creation.

Comment: I mean anything similar for Fedora.

Comment: Oh okay. Try Distrowatch's search page, there is an option to search distro's based on a particular one. http://distrowatch.com/search.php

Answer (score 1):

If you want cutting edge stuff, Fedora is where RedHat does their technology previews.

If you want something more stable -- ie security and bug updates only, not new versions of things -- look into one of the rebuilds of RHEL.  CentOS is a good place to start.

Fedora is updated with new stuff faster, but it also gets obsolete faster so you have to do updates.  RHEL/CentOS is supported longer so you don't have to upgrade, but you'll find that the user-facing applications get long in the tooth.

Comment: Just to update this answer CentOS rebuilds which were almost identical to Redhat are being replaced with CentOS stream which is kind of like a beta. See for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/404949/162453. There are some other free rebuilds and new ones are being added such as [rocky](https://rockylinux.org/)