# Are there any linux distributions similar to RedHat 5 Enterprise?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, linux-distributions

I want to install RedHat 5 Enterprise Edition server on my home PC. I will install servers and clients on virtual machines using Virtual box and study server-client structure at home. But RedHat EE is not free. Instead, I will install a linux server distribution similar to RedHat 5 EE. But I don't know which one is most similar. I know that Fedora is based on RH but it doesn't have a server edition. What are my options?

Comment: Actually, RHEL is based on Fedora.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RedHat for desktops](http://superuser.com/questions/81294/redhat-for-desktops)

Comment: Better duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/15602/is-there-a-free-as-in-money-version-of-redhat-linux

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Centos](http://www.centos.org/) is basically RHEL recompiled from scratch, and i believe their version numbers are identical to their RHEL counterparts - Its commonly used as a replacement for RHEL. You might also want to consider [scientific linux](http://www.scientificlinux.org/), which is another RHEL derivative, and is almost identical.

RHEL has archives of quite a few versions in the 5.x family, while SL has 5.7

Comment: Thanks. Can I use virtual machines as server and clients using Centos?

Comment: I would consider CentOS closer to RHEL than SL; CentOS only changes the trademarks, whereas SL admits to changing/supplementing the package composition on their homepage.

Comment: @alwbtc : yes you can.